# Why my method fails with the "boolean expression must not be null" exception, but SharedPreferences.getBool() don't?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Dart and I'm wondering why I can't return null instead of a bool value in a method like this:

```
bool getFoo(SharedPreferences sp) {
  return sp.getBool('foo');
}
```

But the `SharedPreferences.getBool()` method can return null:

```
bool getBool(String key) => _preferenceCache[key];
```

Both methods have the same return value type-hint. But the Dart's standard lib method can return null. When I call `getFoo(prefs)` I'm getting the exception `Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null` in my method, not in the Dart's std lib method. Why? What's the difference? Why two methods with the same type-hint definition behave differently?

Comment: did u use `setBool("foo",true)`?

Comment: No. My question is not about "how to solve this error". My question is why `SharedPreferences.getBool` can return null, but my method can't?

Comment: It's not about "you can't return null value" - your code is correct and wouldn't throw any exception itself. It's about that assertion fails somewhere in the code. You're trying to pass null value somewhere you are not supposed to.

Comment: Like @IgorKharakhordin said, your function is fine and returning null, just search your code to see where you are using the value, and handle the null value there or you can return a 'false' or 'true' as default if the "foo" is null.

Comment: have you solved the issue

Comment: You were right, the issue was in the `if` statement. It doesn't accept nulls and doesn't cast null to boolean false.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in how the two functions treat the return of `null`.
Currently, all Dart functions with a `bool` return type can return `null` because all Dart types are nullable.

That doesn't mean that you can use `null` as a boolean, just as you can't call string methods on a `null` value with static type `String`. The `null` value represents the absence of an actual value, so if you end up using `null` in a condition (`if`, `while`, `?:`) then you will get the error that you are now seeing.

Dart does not have coercion between different types, and you cannot treat a non-boolean value as a boolean, not even `null`. Obviously the language could have chosen to do so, say treat all non-`true` values as `false` (like it did in Dart 1, before the stricter type system of Dart 2), but it's actually fairly arbitrary whether `null` should mean `true` or `false`, so instead `null` means the absence of a boolean value, and therefore not being able to choose a branch of an `if` statement. This is consistent with all other places where `null` can flow, but its an error if it does and you try to use the value.

When Dart gets non-nullable types, then the conditions will be required to be (statically typed as) non-nullable booleans. This ensures that a `null` value cannot accidentally flow to a position where it is attempted used.

If you know that your result might be null, you can always substitute a default value explicitly: `if (maybeBool ?? false) ...`
Again, with non-nullable types, you will have to do that, if you haven't handled the `null` value earlier.

Comment: You're right. The only exception is that in the case of non-nullable types the author of a function must ensure what it returns and the language will fail a return if it tries to return null. In Dart's case, a user of a function must care for the return value, which is a shift of responsibility from code authors to code users. And that's what I can't understand at all. I can accept it as I can't change it, but I can't see any logical benefits. The true type-strict way is to allow explicit nullable types definition. The Dart's way is a partly-strict one promoting bad development prictices.

Comment: You know, I saw lines like `if (boolFunc() ?? false)` or `if (boolFunc() == true)` out of early beginner programmers in other languages. Dart is shifting us back to this style. It forces developers to check the meaning of null while itself it doesn't sure what the `bool` type means. If I ask some typed code to return boolean it MUST return boolean or fail. But not in Dart's world :) To be safe in "typed" Dart you must check all boolean variables, fields, and methods against possible null value. This line of code is valid and funny in a typed language: `bool foo = null;`

Comment: All types in the current Dart are nullable. That doesn't mean that they are necessarily `null`. A function with a `bool` return type should be assumed to return a non-`null` value unless otherwise documented. You should not *check* that the value is not `null`, because it isn't. If it does turn out to be `null` anyway, then it's an *error*, and failing in that case is the right thing to do. APIs are protocols, and you should assume that the protocols are followed. If a function says that it returns only even integers, it's an error if it returns 3, not something you should always check for.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was in the `if` statement. It doesn't accept nulls and doesn't cast null to boolean false. It requires a boolean value. I came to Dart from PHP and JavaScript so this moment was very unobvious for me. And I didn't read documentation carefully: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#if-and-else.

I actually can't see any profits from this strictness like in strictly typed languages while I can return the null result for a scalar type. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22 - this is the very early issue that Dart lang developers still implementing, but promise to finish it soon.